# Can I automatically log in to open WiFi that requires web login/password?

Tags: wi-fi

There are lots of wifi hotspots that are open, but require a web-based login to use. Hotels, coffeeshops, workplaces. For password-protected wifi, it's easy to set up Android phones to remember the login and password. But I'd like to be able to use my workplace's open wifi with web-based password on a regular basis, without having to manually type stuff in. It should just automatically connect to the Wifi router, go to http://1.1.1.1 or whatever, type in my password, and then everything else should just work. Is this possible?

(HTC Evo running Android 2.2, fwiw...)

Comment: You might be able to do that with tasker, but it's paid.

Comment: How do you set up on android to remember the user/pass?

Answer (score 9):

The best you can do is set it up to auto-connect to the network and then manually open a browser when you're in range.  Save the username and password in the browser.  That gets it down to 2 clicks (er... touches).  Make sure Remember Passwords is on the the browser's settings.

There are some apps that claim to do what you want but I've never used them.  [Here](https://www.appszoom.com/android-apps/auto-login-hotspots) is a list.

Answer (score 8):

[WIFI Web Login](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidyou.wifiloginnew) works great for those that require a username/password or an email, or even just a checkbox to agree the EULA.

Comment: This is a $2.99 app in the store now.

Comment: I noticed a couple of things in its configuration: a) don't put hotspot login UR, b) to run this app on background, disable it from battery optimization.