# How can I automate the Hotspot login process?

Tags: wi-fi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I automatically log in to open WiFi that requires web login/password?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/823/can-i-automatically-log-in-to-open-wifi-that-requires-web-login-password)

Scenario: I go into a coffeeshop, I fire up my droid, and it says it's on the webs. But as soon as I start surfing it bounces me to the establishment's wifi signon page. I agree, click the button, and (I'm assuming) it sticks the droid's MAC address in a table and lets my traffic through. If I return to said coffeeshop within 24hrs, I'm usually still there.

Problem: My droid is WiFi only, I have no cell contract. So If I walk in and forget to fire up the browser, I won't get any texts or calls.

Solution: Does anyone know of an app that would automate this process? The droid itself will hit the wireless network as soon as it comes within range, provided I've used it before. But then it'd be nice if it tried to fetch a webpage, got redirected, and responded automatically.

Alternative: If there is no such app, would you guys be interested in a free one if I took the time to cook one up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several Hotspot apps around which can automate this. An example would be [WiFi Web Login](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidyou.wifiloginnew). I didn't check this one (but used a similar some time ago): As soon as the Wifi comes in reach, your device should connect (provided you did it once manually). If the Hotspot app is running in background, it should pick up from there. You have to record the session once for this to work, it's like a macro-recorder.

Comment: Marking as the correct answer because it's exactly what I was looking for. However, that particular app seems kinda buggy. It worked a few times and then it started disabling the record button. It would say that I had wifi access and no internet connection, but the button was disabled so I couldn't record. Good idea though.

Comment: @LoveMeSomeCode You might try one of the others. It's a while ago when I last had use for these, but my experience then also was partly mixed. So I only could show you the concept -- and as it turns out, that was what you were looking for ;)

Comment: @izzy should either update or delete, the app isn't avail anymore.

Comment: Neither nor. The app is just an example, @slm

Comment: It still exists: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidyou.wifiloginnew

Comment: Thanks for the finding, @TeNNoX – edit accepted!

Comment: Re: edit, comparing the developer and the screenshots from [the previous package name](https://apkcombo.com/wifi-web-login/co.uk.syslynx.wifiwebloginapp/), looks like it's a different app having the same name and same function. But I guess it doesn't matter if it's just an example...

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully automated (and possibly not too helpful for you yet depending which phone you've got) but Android 4.1 (Jellybean) does detect when Wifi Hotspots have a landing page, and pops up a notification which will take you straight to the hotspot's login page.

Notification bar:

[image: Notification bar with Wifi notification]

Pulled down Notification:

[image: Notification window with sign into wifi prompt]

I only noticed this last week when I was having to do some work from a coffee shop. The notification happened on my Galaxy Nexus phone and my Motorola Xoom tablet (both running Jellybean).