# Free Wi-Fi network: how to autoaccept (robotic click) wifi policy web page?

Tags: wi-fi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I automatically log in to open WiFi that requires web login/password?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/823/can-i-automatically-log-in-to-open-wifi-that-requires-web-login-password)

At a hospital, there is a no-password Wi-Fi network which is for guest and prior having internet, I have to click "Accept" button on an initial web page I get in a browser. The page is super simple, single frame with single button at the bottom called accept.

There is an app in the play store which can open browser so that **I** can click the accept button.(app name: Auto Wi-Fi Prompt) 
Well, is there a way to write such script which will make even the "accept" click for me? (e.g., llama advanced config and a ".bat" file after that)

for example, once I activate Wi-Fi, it detects being connected to hospital-guest and will auto-click accept for me.

Comment: Another question which may be related: [How can I automate the Hotspot login process?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27817/how-can-i-automate-the-hotspot-login-process)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you looked very hard in the Play Store. I found several apps which look like they'll do what you want. (I searched on "[wifi auto login](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=wifi+auto+login&c=apps)".)

- [Wifi Browser Login](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wifibrowserlogin) "This app will automatically detect if your WiFi connection requires browser login.
  It can be configured to either notify you or automatically popup a webview for you to login."
- [WiFi Web Login](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.syslynx.wifiwebloginapp) "Automatically logs you on to any WiFi hotspot, hotel WiFi, guest WiFi."
- [WiFi Auto Login Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ybu.wifiautologin) "WiFi Auto-Login automatically logs in your Android device into some of the most popular FREE WiFi hotspots, eliminating the need to deal with that annoying WiFi hotspot login page!"
- ...plus a bunch more. There's quite a few that have a very fine focus, such as one just for [Starbucks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.crocodile.sbautologin).

Comment: The last two of those are trail->payment junk just FYI. Something this simple should always be free.