# How can I automatically connect to my company's wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s-6

My Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 7.0 automatically connects to my home wifi when in range. However, in my company, it only shows me a notification that I can click on to connect to the company's wifi (which then makes me accept terms by clicking on a button every single time.)

Is there any way to make this at least partially automatic, i.e. opening the page with the button automatically instead of just showing a notification? Or even saving my answer to this wifi page and using it during the next connection attempts?

Comment: So you are connecting to your companies guest WiFi which uses a captive portal, meaning you have to acknowledge T&C before use? This functionality is part of the WiFi network, not your device, it's authentication is typically only a few hours or a day or so, then must be redone. The only way around this would be to get your IT dept to whitelist your device's MAC address so it doesn't have to accept T&C, similar to how you would whitelist a gaming console at a hotel.

Comment: Thanks for telling me what they are called, that makes googling for solutions easier! I still don't see what prevents my device from doing this automatically. Even if it means doing e.g. a GET or POST request, I can't believe there's no software that automates this.

Comment: It would kind of defeat the entire purpose of a captured portal to have software to automate bypassing it. Each captive portal uses it's own unique way to authenticate you and to purposely defeat bypass attempts, each individual system would have to have a bypass mechanism build, there is no generic one. The right way to do this would be to either get your IT dept to whitelist your device, or use a different corporate network that does NOT require you to accept T&C, but honestly that would probably be against your organizations security policy. Sorry I don't really have an answer, just info

Comment: Oh, but those defeating apps [do indeed exist](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_finder#group_429), @acejavelin – and I've succesfully used at least one in the past (on vacation, to connect to the hotel WiFi, which used a captive portal).

Comment: @Izzy Never said they didn't... I just won't recommend any. :)

Comment: @acejavelin that would be a task for SoftwareRec.SE, sure :) I've not used any of them for quite a while, so I'd know none to recommend. But for a network you trust, why not?

Comment: Didn't know that site existed! Finally :)

Comment: [This](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28515/39544) and the duplicates do not help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be completely automated.

First, you need to know how button click data is submitted to the server: GET (less likely) or POST

If data is submitted to server using GET, just record the URL after submission. If data is submitted using POST, intercept the HTTP header when you click the button (there are lots of softwares for that; for example [this Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/eaiimeeggnhceafhencnejheejddlcpa) can log everything).

Now, install [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) in your Android device.

1. Set Trigger as `State` ~> `Net` ~> `Wi-Fi Connected` and enter SSID of company Wi-Fi.
2. Set Action as `Net` ~> `HTTP GET` or `Browse URL` if button click data is submitted using GET. Otherwise, set Action as `Net` ~> `HTTP POST` or `HTTP Head` and enter the intercepted HTTP head data.

Answer (score 3):

You can give a try to the app [WIFI Web Auth](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.hol.galvisoft.wifiwebauth). It can simulate clicking a button or filling out input fields.

Comment: Hello. What is your affiliation with the app WiFi Web Auth? The app has mere 34 reviews and just 1000+ installs. Furthermore, you tried to add this app as a recommendation in [this edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/208559) too which is no less than a spam. I urge you to read our policy on  [promotion](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). It is one thing to find an app useful and recommend it, but it is another thing to suggest it as if only promoting it.

Comment: I'm not the author of this app. My intention was not to promote it. (Perhaps i should do, because it's really good.) I was just searching for a tool that can automate the login process, and it turned out for me, there are not that many tool, that really can do this. So i just thought it could be maybe useful for others as well...