# Completing HTTP POST request when wireless network connects

Tags: applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I automatically log in to open WiFi that requires web login/password?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/823/can-i-automatically-log-in-to-open-wifi-that-requires-web-login-password)

My school requires that students using the wireless sign in using an HTTP POST prompt each time they connect. It's a very simple username and password at a set IP address. I'm wondering  if there's some way to automatically login to this when my tablet connects to the network. If not, how hard would it be to code an app that accomplishes this.

Comment: It's possible that [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) will do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using [onx.ms](http://onx.ms). You'll need to know a bit of scripting, but it's not that hard. onx.ms is basically an automation tool much like Tasker.

onx.ms has the ability to automatically run the script you made at specific triggers (like Wi-Fi on/off). These triggers itself are to be defined within the script you make.

Have a look at [this](https://www.onx.ms/#apiPage/httpClient) for the HTTPClient object you can use in the script to make this happen.

Though not a perfect app as it requires some internet action initially I presume and the fact that you'll need to have a facebook account to use it. But the whole javascript like scripting and not-so-bad documentation, makes it more fun to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not compatible with the nexus 7. (Yet?) Any other ideas? By the way, I know java and am all for learning a new language.

Comment: @Zonedabone Have you tried Tasker? I've seen it having modules like "http POST/GET" that can fire up on certain triggers..much like onx.ms itself.