# Connect to internet via proxy

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, internet, proxy

My office network is connected via proxy. While I connect to the internet(via browser) using mobile Wi-Fi, it asks for user name and password. When I enter the user name and password, it connects to the internet.
But when I open Google Play store , I see 'Server error' means it could not connect to the internet. How can I fix the issue ?

Comment: See if any of these help: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46999/google-play-store-says-no-connection-retry

Comment: Please post updates of your findings.

Comment: That's a so-called "captive portal" as it sounds. You might have to login first using your browser, and then everything else should pick-up the connection. For automation, you might want to take a look at [Can I automatically log in to open WiFi that requires web login/password?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/823/16575) If it's a different proxy, you might want to check our [other questions tagged proxy](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proxy) or [proxy & wi-fi](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proxy+wi-fi).

Answer (score -3):

if you are rooted,Use proxy droid. Apps use different settings than the ones u provide in the wifi. so not only will your google play not work but also whatsapp and such apps. for that you would need a global proxy. and for that u need to be rooted. You install proxy droid.install iptables. and then ur done

Comment: Can you provide a link?